# Copy messages between Azure ServiceBus queues

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

How can you copy a messages from one Azure ServiceBus queue to another?

We have a queue containing a few gigabytes of messages that need to be moved from one queue to another.  How can this be achieved either programmatically with PowerShell or Dotnet, or using some sort of tooling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can create a [Azure service bus queue trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp) to copy message, you need to add [service bus queue output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp). Please refer to my code sample:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FrankServiceBus
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        [return: ServiceBus("<your-queue-out>", Connection = "connectionString")]
        public static String Run([ServiceBusTrigger("<your-queue-in>", Connection = "connectionString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
            return myQueueItem;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are not familiar with Azure function, please refer to [Getting started with Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-get-started?pivots=programming-language-csharp).

Comment: Thanks Frank, but the messages are already in the queue.

Comment: @SeanKearon, Don't you want to copy messages from one queue to another queue?

Comment: The service bus queue trigger can be triggered by a message already in the queue, and then send the message to another queue through output binding (another queue).

Comment: Oooooohh - thanks, Frank.  I didn't realise that...that's what we want to acheive!